# Created mvc project and published but newly-added folder did not follow

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I created an MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 and published it to Azure and it worked great. I made some changes by adding an image folder under content. Well, when I went to publish my changes to Azure, that folder did not get published.

I had to manually right-click on the folder in Solution Explorer and publish it separately. Can I do this automatically?

Comment: was the reference to the new folder and files added to the csproj file?

Comment: Is your tag of visual-studio-2010 maybe incorrect?

Comment: This question probably needs a [mcve] to be answerable. In the interests of curation, I will try to put it on hold for now.

Comment: Have you include your image folder and its content in the project? If you can see that new folder in solution explorer then you should be able to see it after publish.